# Detect iPhone EndEvent

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, events, video

Basically, I need to be able to recognize when a video ends and take action based on that end event. I've seen it done here on the Onion's site (http://www.theonion.com/video/nike-releases-new-olympic-track-suits-designed-to,28621/?ref=auto). I've looked through the JS code on the page and can't seem to find the code that is recognizing the end of the ad.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the media property `onended` to determine, whether a video has reached it's end and do something afterwards:

```
<video […] id="video" onended="doSomeFancyStuff();"> … </video>
```

Or with jQuery, this should work:

```
$('#video').bind('ended', function() {
    // do some fancy stuff
});
```

I didn't test both, so no guarantee here. :)

**EDIT**

I created two fiddles to test both and both are working just fine on an iPhone with iOS 5.1.

Here is the link that just hast the event handler attached as an attribute:

http://jsfiddle.net/insertusernamehere/X3Lat/

And this is the one with jQuery handling the event:

http://jsfiddle.net/insertusernamehere/RjGAR/

Comment: I haven't tried the first option, but the second was my most recent iteration. It worked until around the time iOS 5 came out. I suspect that something at a higher level than I understand changed and stopped it from working.

Comment: That is strange. I've to create a simple webpage with HTML5-video at the end of this week. I hope I get some time to try both on my iPad. Maybe I can figure out something.

Comment: I'd love to hear the results you get.

Comment: Please see my edited post and try both on your iPhone. Maybe you have a corrupt file in your tests, which has a broken ending.

Comment: Marvelous. Thanks very much! I think I'll be able to incorporate the code successfully.